# Eclipse javascript editor

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I have a good / working / updated javascript editor for Eclipse v2023-12?

I tried to update my eclipse to last version (2023-12 v4.30), to install Eclipse Web Developer Tools, Eclipse Web Tools Platform    Chromium JavaScript, but the JS editor is no more than a simple text editor, it doesn't recognize modern keywords.

This is my update site: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The "JS Editor" is really only there for Chromium debugging. You should be using [Wild Web Developer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-nodejs-angular-json-yaml-kubernetes-xml) for anything else regarding JavaScript.